# User Clearing a ComboBox by Pressing a Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a ComboBox on a WPF view and I want the user to be able to clear the selected item by pressing a other button on the form.

Here's the ComboBox:

```
  <ComboBox Name="Relationship" FontWeight="Bold"
        DisplayMemberPath="Description" SelectedValuePath="Code"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Form104CModel.SelectedRelationship, Mode=TwoWay}"
        >
        <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <domain:Enumeration Code="" Description="" />
                <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={x:Static infraData:CodeCache.VictimSuspectRelationship}}" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
    </ComboBox>
```

And here's the code in the Model:

```
//this.AddOtherVictimCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnAddVictimExecuted);

private void OnDeleteVictimExecuted(object InvNum)
{
    //  This method is called to set the default relationship for victim-to-suspect.  
    //  It is called when either the SelectedVictim or SelectedSuspect properties are set.  
    //  It searches the relationships collection by victim involvement number and suspect 
    //      involvement number. 
    //  When a match is found on both involvement numbers, it sets the SelectedRelationship 
    //      property to the relationship in the relationships collection.  
    //   If no match is found, nothing happens.
    // 
    int a = this.Relationships.Count;
    this.SelectedRelationship = null;
    //if ((this.SelectedSuspect != null) & (this.SelectedVictim != null))
    //{
    //    for (int i = 0; i < this.Relationships.Count; i++)
    //    {
    //        if (this.Relationships[i].SuspectNumber == this.SelectedSuspect.InvolvementNumber)
    //            if (this.Relationships[i].VictimNumber == this.SelectedVictim.InvolvementNumber)
    //                this.SelectedRelationship = null;
    //    }
    //}
}
```

As you can see from the code, I've tried some things that didn't work.  It seems like it should be simple, but I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, you'll have to add this line inside your void

```
Relationship.Items.Clear();
```

Final code:

```
private void OnDeleteVictimExecuted(object InvNum)
    {
        Relationship.Items.Clear();
        //
        //  This method is called to set the default relationship for victim-to-suspect.  
        //  It is called when either the SelectedVictim or SelectedSuspect properties are set.  
        //  It searches the relationships collection by victim involvement number and suspect 
        //      involvement number. 
        //  When a match is found on both involvement numbers, it sets the SelectedRelationship 
        //      property to the relationship in the relationships collection.  
        //   If no match is found, nothing happens.
        // 
        int a = this.Relationships.Count;
        this.SelectedRelationship = null;
        //if ((this.SelectedSuspect != null) & (this.SelectedVictim != null))
        //{
        //    for (int i = 0; i < this.Relationships.Count; i++)
        //    {
        //        if (this.Relationships[i].SuspectNumber == this.SelectedSuspect.InvolvementNumber)
        //            if (this.Relationships[i].VictimNumber == this.SelectedVictim.InvolvementNumber)
        //                this.SelectedRelationship = null;
        //    }
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Adding one line "Relationships.Items.Clear()" didn't work.  Relationships is the source of the ComboBox list.  I want to clear the selected item.